# issue regarding wishlist component in virtuemart v1.19

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, favorite

I am new in joomla. I am trying to implement virtuemart in joomla 1.5. I install virtuemart v1.1.19 . Now I want to add "add to favotite" and "Wishlist" in virtuemart. Can I get theose component free? If so how can do this? Please help me.

Comment: This is programming related forum.

Answer (score 0):

All extensions for Joomla can be found on the [Joomla extensions directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/)

There are 557 specific extensions for VirtueMart on JED so I'm sure something will pop up.

This is a commercial extension but serves both purposes:

http://extensions.virtuemart.net/component/sobi2/?sobi2Task=sobi2Details&sobi2Id=128&Itemid=2